# The connection has been terminated, and this cursor is dead

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, zend-framework2

I want to populate a mongodb database with data using doctrine and zend-framework2.

Everything works fine until the number of records in a collection grows to about 2 million and then I get the following exception:

```
The connection has been terminated, and this cursor is dead
```

Can anybody tell me why this exception is thrown and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> the connection has been terminated, and this cursor is dead

You provide no real information however I am guessing you are doing a query on these 2 million record WITHOUT an index. This means the cursor is most likely running out of steam and timing out because either your query or your iteration of the result set is too slow.

I recommend you look into indexing: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/